# Can multiple instances of WKWebView in the same app have a separate cookie store?

Tags: webkit, ios9, session-cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a couple of `WKWebViews` in my app. I don't want the cookies/auth to be shared between them. I tried using separate instances of `WKProcessPool` and `WKWebViewConfiguration` to initialize the other webview. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u find the solution?

Comment: @ZAFAR007 I haven't tried after that.

Answer (score 0):

The WKWebsiteDataStore is per url based. So the datastore (which includes cookie store) is shared based on website/url loaded using WKWebView.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore

> A WKWebsiteDataStore object represents various types of data used by a
>   chosen website. Data types include cookies, disk and memory caches,
>   and persistent data such as WebSQL, IndexedDB databases, and local
>   storage.